# Subsetting a data frame with square brackets in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I am just starting with R, and ran into the following issue.

Subsetting data frames with square brackets in the same way seems to result in either in a vector or in a data frame. Why is this difference? Below are the two data frames that I am trying to subset.

First data frame `matching` that I subset with `matching[,1]`, which gives me a data frame with only one column.

```
> attributes(matching)
$names
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H"

$row.names
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
[50] 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67

$class
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

> matching[,1]
# A tibble: 67 x 1
       A
   <int>
 1     1
 2     2
 3     3
 4     4
 5     5
 6     6
 7     7
 8     8
 9     9
10    10
# ... with 57 more rows
>
```

Second data frame `files` that I subset with `files[,1]` which gives me a vector

```
> attributes(files)
$names
[1] "names"

$row.names
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
[50] 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62

$class
[1] "data.frame"

> files[,1]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
[50] 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62
```

The first was created with `read_excel` from excel files, and the second with `data.frame()` from a vector of character strings.

Thank you!

Comment: Try `files[,1, drop = FALSE]`.

Comment: `read_excel()` comes from the `readxl` package, which is part of RStudio's tidyverse set of packages. The function returns what RStudio calls a "tibble", which is their re-imagining of data frames. Among other features, tibbles are stricter than data frames when using `[` and `[[`. With tibbles, `[` always subsets to another tibble, and `[[` returns a vector.

Comment: Instead of files[,1, drop = FALSE] you can also do files[1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see from the class that `matching` is a tibble and `files` is a dataframe.  This is one of the differences between a tibble and dataframe objects.

```
matching <- mtcars %>% as_tibble()
files <- mtcars
```

Subset one column from tibble

```
matching[, 1]

# A tibble: 32 x 1
#     mpg
#   <dbl>
# 1  21  
# 2  21  
# 3  22.8
# 4  21.4
# 5  18.7
# 6  18.1
# 7  14.3
# 8  24.4
# 9  22.8
#10  19.2
# … with 22 more rows
```

Subset a column from dataframe

```
files[, 1]
# [1] 21.0 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4 
#     10.4 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2 27.3 26.0 30.4 15.8 19.7 
#     15.0 21.4
```

When you subset dataframe, by default `drop = TRUE`. In `?Extract` you can see

> drop  - If TRUE the result is coerced to the lowest possible dimension.

However tibbles by default have `drop = FALSE`. In `?"tbl_df-class"`

> df[, j] returns a tibble; it does not automatically extract the column inside. df[, j, drop = FALSE] is the default.

To make dataframe behave as tibble you can do

```
files[,1, drop = FALSE]
```